# In django-registration i am not getting any confirmation link?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

Actually when I register with a user name it redirects to registration-completion page.But when I login with that user name it throws form error. So when I login with my created user name it shows

> "Your username and password didn't match. Please try again"

(which I wrote to show form.errors in login.html )

**login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
<td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
<td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
<td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**registration.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register</title>
</head>   

<body>
  <h2>Register</h2>
  <form action="/accounts/register/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
     <table>
        {{form.as_table}}
     </table>

  <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
  </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
enter code here
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from frm.views import main,forum,thread
from frm.views import reply,new_thread,profile,post
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$',main),
url(r'^forum/(?P<pk>\w+)/$',forum  ),
url(r'^thread/(?P<pk>\w+)/$',thread ),
url(r'^post/(new_thread|reply)/(\d+)',post),
url(r'^new_thread/(\d+)/$',new_thread),
url(r'^reply/(\d+)/$',reply),
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\w+)/$',profile),

# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'forum.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/',include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please detail each of the steps you are taking during the registration process, then post the exact error you are getting. Try and identify where the bug is in your code from the error you see and post that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the errors in the template in many ways.  Try changing:

```
{% if form.errors %}
  <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
```

to:

```
{% if form.errors %}
  {{ form.errors }}
  <br /><br />

  {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
      {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}

    <br /><br />
    a nicer way:<br />
    {{ form.non_field_errors.as_ul }}

  {% endif %}

  <br /><br />
  form username errors:<br />
  {{ form.username.errors }}

  <br /><br />
  form password errors:<br />
  {{ form.password.errors }}
{% endif %}
```

That is a good start.  You will also want to show the errors to your visitors.  Change your `label_tag`s to

`<td>{{form.username.errors }}<br />{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>`

and

`<td>{{form.password.errors }}<br />{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>`

Comment: that's okay but how to confirm that user ? that is my question .

Comment: Any number of errors will throw that message.  You need to see what the actual error is.

Comment: after using this in my template it is showing this account is inactive.This is what I want to know that How to activate my account ?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of your original question.  Activation is done by emailing the user  link to click on to confirm the registration.  Did you check your email?  If in development, and your development environment doesn't send emails, you will need to access the user in the database and switch `is_active` to true.

Comment: okay .. sorry if my question didn't give the idea of what i was asking. So can you tell me how to manually activate the user as it is in development now

Comment: Access the user in the database and switch `is_active` to true.  Or, find the section of your code that stores the newly-registered user.  It should be setting `is_active` to False, until confirmed via email.  Force it to save `is_active` to True while in development.  Then, fix it when you deploy.